# FastAPI with Azure AD: TypeError on OAuth2 Authentication

Tags: python, azure, oauth-2.0, oauth, fastapi

I'm trying to implement Azure AD OAuth2 authentication in a FastAPI application. I have set up the environment variables correctly and configured the OAuth client with Azure AD's endpoints. However, I'm encountering a TypeError: Invalid type for url. Expected str or httpx.URL, got <class 'NoneType'>: None when trying to authenticate a user.

Here's the relevant part of my code:

**FastAPI:**

```
app.add_middleware(SessionMiddleware, secret_key="q803pJMcx6KNkIlBGi_mPQSYiOP0IPze")
#app.add_middleware(TokenVerificationMiddleware)

@app.get("/")
async def health():
    return JSONResponse(content={"status": "healthy"}, status_code=200)


# Redirect to login URL
@app.get("/login")
async def login(request: Request):
    redirect_uri = request.url_for('auth')
    return await oauth.azure.authorize_redirect(request, redirect_uri)

# Callback endpoint
@app.get("/auth")
async def auth(request: Request):
    token = await oauth.azure.authorize_access_token(request)
    user = token.get('userinfo')
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, detail='Authentication failed')
    return user
```

**OAuth2:**

```
from fastapi import Depends, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.security import OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer
from authlib.integrations.starlette_client import OAuth
from starlette.requests import Request
import os

# Load environment variables
CLIENT_ID = os.getenv("ASPEN_APP_AUTH_CLIENT_ID")
TENANT_ID = os.getenv("ASPEN_APP_AUTH_TENANT_ID")
CLIENT_SECRET = os.getenv("ASPEN_APP_AUTH_SECRET")

# Initialize OAuth2
oauth = OAuth()
oauth.register(
    name='azure',
    client_id=CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET,
    authorize_url=f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
    token_url=f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    client_kwargs={'scope': 'openid email profile'}
)

oauth2_scheme = OAuth2AuthorizationCodeBearer(
    authorizationUrl=f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
    tokenUrl=f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token'
)


async def get_current_user(request: Request, token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme)):
    try:
        response = await oauth.azure.parse_id_token(request, token)
        return response
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail=str(e)
        )
```

The error occurs at the line token = await oauth.azure.authorize_access_token(request). I have verified that the environment variables are set correctly and that the redirect URL in Azure matches exactly.

**My dependencies are as follows:**

```
Python 3.12
uvicorn~=0.23.2
fastapi~=0.103.1
pydantic~=2.4.2
pandas~=2.1.0
requests~=2.31.0
beautifulsoup4~=4.12.2
aiohttp~=3.9.1
pyproj~=3.6.0
python-dateutil~=2.8.2
python-dotenv~=1.0.0
python-jose~=3.3.0
mangum~=0.17.0
SQLAlchemy~=2.0.21
starlette~=0.27.0
bs4~=0.0.1
httpx~=0.23.0
Authlib~=1.2.1
itsdangerous~=2.1.2
boto3~=1.33.12
botocore~=1.33.12
respx>=0.20.1
```

Traceback:

```
#I add some print statements to fetch access token
redirect_uri: http://localhost:8000/auth
metadata: {'token_url': 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/token'}
token_endpoint: None


ERROR:    Exception in ASGI application
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\protocols\http\h11_impl.py", line 408, in run_asgi
    result = await app(  # type: ignore[func-returns-value]
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\uvicorn\middleware\proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\applications.py", line 292, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\applications.py", line 122, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 184, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\errors.py", line 162, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\sessions.py", line 86, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send_wrapper)
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\middleware\exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 20, in __call__
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\middleware\asyncexitstack.py", line 17, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 718, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 276, in handle
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 66, in app
    response = await func(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 273, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 190, in run_endpoint_function
    return await dependant.call(**values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\AspenAPI\fast_api.py", line 56, in auth
    token = await oauth.azure.authorize_access_token(request)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\starlette_client\apps.py", line 82, in authorize_access_token
    token = await self.fetch_access_token(**params, **kwargs)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\base_client\async_app.py", line 128, in fetch_access_token
    token = await client.fetch_token(token_endpoint, **params)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\httpx_client\oauth2_client.py", line 125, in _fetch_token
    resp = await self.post(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1842, in post
    return await self.request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\authlib\integrations\httpx_client\oauth2_client.py", line 90, in request
    return await super(AsyncOAuth2Client, self).request(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 1514, in request
    request = self.build_request(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 344, in build_request
    url = self._merge_url(url)
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\ServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_client.py", line 374, in _merge_url
    merge_url = URL(url)
                ^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\X\PycharmProjects\AspenServicesAPI\venv\Lib\site-packages\httpx\_urls.py", line 102, in __init__
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: Invalid type for url.  Expected str or httpx.URL, got <class 'NoneType'>: None
```

I suspect there might be an issue with the dependencies, specifically httpx and authlib, but I'm not sure how to resolve this. Any insights or suggestions on what might be causing this error and how to fix it would be greatly appreciated.

**Update : 12/12/2023**

Using python 3.11 or 3.9 didn't work. However, I discovered that renaming 'toke_url' to 'token_endpoint' eliminates the initial error. Additionally, incorporating 'jwks_uri' seems to resolve a subsequent error. But now, I'm encountering a new issue: a 'KeyError' associated with 'id_token'. I have updated my post with more details for further insight.

```
 JWKS_URI = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TENANT_ID}/discovery/v2.0/keys".format(TENANT_ID=ASPEN_APP_AUTH_TENANT_ID)

# Initialize OAuth2
oauth = OAuth()
oauth.register(
    name='azure',
    client_id=ASPEN_APP_AUTH_CLIENT_ID,
    client_secret=ASPEN_APP_AUTH_SECRET,
    authorize_url=f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{ASPEN_APP_AUTH_TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
    token_endpoint=f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{ASPEN_APP_AUTH_TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    token_url=f'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{ASPEN_APP_AUTH_TENANT_ID}/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    client_kwargs={'scope': 'openid email profile'},
    jwks_uri=JWKS_URI
)
```

**Fixed**

Replacing 'toke_url' to 'token_endpoint' **fixed** Expected str or httpx.URL, got <class 'NoneType'>

than issue with token_id was fixed like this :

```
@app.get("/auth")
async def auth(request: Request):
    try:
        token = await oauth.azure.authorize_access_token(request)
        nonce = token.get('userinfo').get('nonce')
        # Parse the ID token
        user_info = await oauth.azure.parse_id_token(token=token, nonce=nonce)
        return {"user_info": user_info}
    except HTTPException as e:
        raise e
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error during authentication:", str(e))
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Authentication failed.")
```

I'm uncertain if this is the correct approach, but it seems to be functioning as intended for me. If there are any errors or security issues in what I've done, please let me know.

Comment: What is your python version?

Comment: Python 3.12 - @Goku-standswithPalestine